# Calculate model BoundingBox in osgEarth

Tags: osgearth

I want draw a model BoundingBox in osgEarth, but position is not suitable.

```
osg::ComputeBoundsVisitor boundVisitor;

node->accept(boundVisitor);

osg::BoundingBox boundingBox = boundVisitor.getBoundingBox();

osg::Matrixd localToWorld = osg::computeLocalToWorld(paath);
```

Now the bounding box model is perpendicular to the ground, but the direction is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful if you:

- Post the rest of the code used to position your box
- Include a screenshot of the problem
- Explain what you are expecting to see

Thanks!